# `npm pack` is not including/excluding files as expected

Tags: node.js, npm

I've done some research on explicitly including/excluding files when publishing an npm package. I was able to see the file size change using `npm publish --dry-run` however when I try to actually test it using `npm pack` there is no difference. I've tried the following individually, I know that if I do more than one of these at the same time it won't work.

1. `.npmignore` to exclude specified files
2. `files` array in `package.json` to include certain files.
3. `.gitignore`, since `npm publish` is supposed to automatically exclude those files.

I came across a couple GitHub issues in the npm repo, however both of these have been closed without a solution.

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7435
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4479

How can I apply my file inclusion/exclusion and verify it locally with `npm pack` so that I don't have to do trial and error with `npm publish`?